# How to get execution ID in workflow

Tags: google-workflows

When executing a workflow there is a unique `Execution ID`. Is it possible to access this value from within the workflow. For example, if I was to use the Execution ID as the filename in a step:

````
        url: https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/bucketname/o
        headers:
            Content-Type: application/json
        query:
            uploadType: media
            name: ${string(EXECUTION_ID) + ".json"}
    ```
````

Answer (score 3):

It is now available as environment variable GOOGLE_CLOUD_WORKFLOW_EXECUTION_ID which can be accessed like this in your yaml configuration file:

```
${sys.get_env("GOOGLE_CLOUD_WORKFLOW_EXECUTION_ID")}
```

Comment: It is nowadays available as env variable `GOOGLE_CLOUD_WORKFLOW_EXECUTION_ID `